# Memtime Alternatives

Tags: linux, performance-testing

Are there alternatives for this tool on Linux environment ? This [tool](http://www.update.uu.se/~johanb/memtime/) (*A tool for measuring memory and time used when executing a command.*) is very old.

Answer (score 2):

Not the correct place to ask such a thing, try [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

But the answer would be [time](http://www.gnu.org/directory/time.html)

```
alias time='/usr/bin/time -f "\nCPU: %Us\tReal: %es\tRAM: %MKB"'
```